# Can I interact with google earth using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, automation, google-earth

The only thing that I could do is open the kml file using

```
import os 

os.startfile("C:\Users\Nemi\Desktop\pointsunedit.kml")
```

Then I would like to create a network link using python command. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: The Google Earth API was [deprecated in 2014 and retired in 2015](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html).